# UWP Optional package in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Visual Studio 2017 includes a project template for creating optional packages in C#. However, there is no corresponding project template for C++/WinRT. Is there any way to create the same kind of optional package using C++/WinRT in Visual Studio?

Comment: What did you mean about 'a project template for creating optional packages in C#'?

Comment: VS2017->File->New->Project...->Visual C#->Windows Universal->Optional Code Package (Universal Windows)

Answer (score 0):

There's no separate 'Optional Code Package' visual studio template for C++\WinRT. Please see the [OptionalPackageSample](https://github.com/AppInstaller/OptionalPackageSample) repository on GitHub. It creates a [OptionalPackageDLL](https://github.com/AppInstaller/OptionalPackageSample/tree/master/OptionalPackageDLL) 
 to show how to create a project with code that can be executed from the main package. The MyMainApp project demonstrates how to [load code](https://github.com/AppInstaller/OptionalPackageSample/blob/bf6b4915ff1f3b8abfdaacb1ad9e77184c49fe18/MyMainApp/MainPage.xaml.cpp#L182) from the OptionalPackageDLL.dll file.